# Is it possible to use a predefined function like openssl_decrypt without the openssl module loaded?

Tags: php, php-extension

I know for instance that to use the function `query` of the sqlite3 module you need an instance with `new SQLite3()`, so the module sqlite3 needs to be loaded.

But for functions that you can use directly without instantiation like `openssl_decrypt` do you need the module openssl to be loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a function like `openssl_decrypt` without the module `openssl` loaded because such functions are only provided with their corresponding module.

If the module is not loaded, those functions would be unavailable.